# iPhone - difference between these two lines of code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

What is the diffrence between these two lines of code:

```
[cmController currentPageNo];
self.cmController.currentPageNo;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is actually a functional difference - the second line is equivalent to:

```
[[self cmController] currentPageNo];
```

Using the `-cmController` property getter method to access the `cmController` ivar may have behaviours that make it different to accessing the ivar directly. These might include lazy initialisation or atomic thread locking, or a range of other behaviours. Unless you have a good reason to, you should (in general) use the accessor methods for properties, rather than accessing ivars directly.

So to clarify:

```
[cmController currentPageNo]; // 1
cmController.currentPageNo;   // 2

[[self cmController] currentPageNo]; // 3
self.cmController.currentPageNo;     // 4
```

1 and 2 are functionally identical to each other, but use different syntax. 3 and 4 are also functionally identical to each other, but use different syntax. You should use version 4, or version 3 if you have an aversion to dot-syntax.

Comment: Nicely put; you kept that simple, but it's complete.

Comment: And 3.5 would be [self.cmController currentPageNo];

Comment: Joe: I rarely use self.getters within UIViewController subclasses, and don't see much reason to. Other classes, you might have more reason to.But they're very handy for setters.

Comment: @JoeBlow if you ever decide to lazily initialise a property, it would be very straightforward to change your classes behaviour as long as you were always using the property getter internally. If you used the ivar directly, you would have to change each reference to use the getter. There's other upsides too (like atomicity) - but the only downside to always using the property are 1. performance (which is almost always negligible for a simple getter), and 2. brevity. Brevity is not a good argument when weighed against more maintainable and flexible code.

Comment: Also - ambiguity. `self.thingController` is very explicit - you know exactly which object you are referring to. `thingController` on its own could be an ivar, it could be a method argument, or it could be a local stack variable. Any coding practice that reduces ambiguity (and hence, enhances readability) is a good thing in my opinion.

Comment: Maintainability is definitely one of the main reasons, and I personally don't think you can easily dismiss ambiguity. When you have a 1000+ line class (which does happen from time to time), every bit of 'explicitness' helps you understand the code. Sometimes you need to have really long methods, and diving into someone else's code can mean that things like `fileCoordinator` vs `self.fileCoordinator` can make a lot of difference in understanding.

Comment: One last one - I find that it helps my conceptual understanding of a complex OOP design to consider the state within an instance to entirely consist of properties of that instance. I find that the "everything is a property" approach makes it easier and quicker for me to get my head around how everything is represented. I virtually never use ivars directly anymore, except for when I need a performance boost. For mutable collections and other "private" state, I use a property in a class extension.

Comment: Coming from the other thread: A property is just a helper. It does (most of the) memory management for you, it cleans up the code and it avoids scope issues. And encapsulation is just way nicer with properties than with variables. I agree with Joe Blow tho, that in high performance cases they might be the wrong approach. But that's only rarely applicable.

Comment: Twice already this week, I've modified a relatively complex class to initialise a property lazily - which is trivial if you always use the property getter. This is such a no-brainer to me that I don't understand quite why anyone would argue against it! :-) It seems like a case of maintainability/flexibility vs premature optimisation. Premature in that a property getter will be a performance bottleneck probably less than 1% of the time. Anyway, I think I'm repeating myself now, so I'll wrap it up. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Generally, dot notation is just syntactical sugar.

But in this case, there actually is some difference.

```
[cmController currentPageNo];
```

This will use the class's instance variable directly to get your cmController. It will then send the currentPageNo to it.

```
self.cmController.currentPageNo;
```

This, on the other hand, will use the current class's property definition to get the cmController via the class's ivar.

This means, basically, the the first is slightly more efficient than the second. Not because you used dot notation, but because you used cmController directly instead of `self.cmController`. `[whatever currentPageNo]` is the same as `whatever.currentPageNo`.

These lines are equivalent except for the syntax used:

```
[cmController currentPageNo];
cmController.currentPageNo;
```

On the other hand, these lines are equivalent except for the syntax used:

```
self.cmController.currentPageNo;
[[self cmController] currentPageNo];
```

I hope that's clear.

You can read about dot notation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW17).

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference, functionally; objective C 2.0 just introduced the dot notation, giving those who aren't as into the brackets a way out.

EDIT:

As the comments pointed out, of course this is wrong. I was responding to the (unasked) question of "what's the difference between `[cmController currentPageNo];` and `self.cmController.currentPageNo;`?"

[Nick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352609/iphone-difference-between-these-two-lines-of-code/4352652#4352652) gives the true answer, which is that the first line directly accesses the variable, while the second line uses the variable's getter method. The two lines also differ in that the first uses typical bracket notation, while the second does indeed use the new dot notation from objective C 2.0.

Comment: Joe, Brad, you're both right, of course -- this is my fault for trying to knock out a quick answer. I'll throw in a quick edit to reflect this, and be more diligent.